# Proof that the set $ \tilde{D}=\{ (x, y) \in V \times V \mid[x, y] \subseteq D \}$ is open in $V \times V$

Tags: solution-verification, proof-writing

Let $D$ be an open subset of a finite-dimensional real vector space $V$ and
$$
\tilde{D}=\{ (x, y) \in V \times V \mid[x, y] \subseteq D \}.
$$
I would like to show that $\tilde{D}$ is open in $V \times V$.

---

My proof was wrong. I am working on a new version. Thanks for hints.

Comment: Why would you have $[u,v] \subset U_x \times B_y(r)$? They're not even on the same "level": $[u,v]$ lies in $V$ while $U_x \times B_y(r)$ lies in $V \times V$.

Comment: $[u, v] \subseteq U_x \times B_y(r) \subseteq D$ is doubly incorrect, and $U_x \times B_y(r) \subseteq \tilde{D}$ is false.

Comment: It is like a reversed convex hull

Answer (score 3):

$[u, v] \subseteq U_x \times B_y(r) \subseteq D$ is doubly incorrect, and $U_x \times B_y(r) \subseteq \tilde{D}$ is generally false. Here is a sketch of an alternative proof:

Since the compact segment $[x,y]$ is disjoint from the closed subset $D^\complement,$ their distance $r$ is positive. $B_x(r)\times B_y(r)\subseteq\tilde D.$